# Error BaseExpandableListAdapter textview null

Tags: android, adapter

I have a problem, I'm doing an android application and I want to do a list a question and when we click on one question it scroll a list of answer (in a fragment).
I did a Custom adapter and I want to add a footer after the list of answer for each question (I want to add a edittext to add an anwser).

And when I scroll the list of answer for one question it's working well with the footer but when I try to scroll a second time the same list, he say me that the textview is null...

Here the code :

```
-> adapter


public class MyExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context context;
private LinkedList<Question> groups;

public MyExpandableAdapter(Context context, LinkedList<Question> groups)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.groups = groups;
}
@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return groups.size();
}

//Add 2 to childcount. The first row and the last row are used as header and footer to childview
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
    return groups.get(i).getListAnswer().size() + 1 ;
}

@Override
public Question getGroup(int i) {
    return groups.get(i);
}

@Override
public Answer getChild(int i, int i2) {
    return groups.get(i).getListAnswer().get(i2);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int i, int i2) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
{
    Question currentQuestion = groups.get(i);
    if(view == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listquestion_home,null);
    }
    ((CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listrow_group_question)).setText(currentQuestion.getQuestion());
    ((CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listrow_group_question)).setChecked(true);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listrow_group_author)).setText("Anonymous" + currentQuestion.getUserId().toString());
    return view;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean b, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    //Here is the ListView of the ChildView

    if (childPosition < getChildrenCount(groupPosition) - 1)
    {
        Answer answer = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listanswer_home, null);
        }

        TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text.setText(answer.getAnswer());

        //the last row is used as footer
    }
    else
    {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_edit_text, null);
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i2) {
    return false;
}
```

}

-> Fragment code :

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
    ExpandableListView listView = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    MyExpandableAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableAdapter(getActivity(), QuestionManager.getQuestionManager().getQuestionWithAnswerNotFromMe());
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return rootView;
}
```

XML code :

-> Answer

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="40dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="hey"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black" />
```

-> Question

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
>

<CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/listrow_group_question"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingLeft="32dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:text="Test"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"

    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listrow_group_author"
    android:layout_below="@id/listrow_group_question"
    android:gravity="right"

    />
```

-> Footer

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtFooter"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Footer" />
```

The error is in the adapter : 
            text.setText(answer.getAnswer());

I really don't understand. I add one of the size of child for it but the bug appear when I do this...

If you have any idea :'( !

Thank you

Log :

01-06 15:03:39.845 23899-23899/com.example.thibault.project_mobile E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

01-06 15:03:39.845 23899-23899/com.example.thibault.project_mobile E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.thibault.project_mobile.MyExpandableAdapter.getChildView(MyExpandableAdapter.java:92)

01-06 15:03:39.845 23899-23899/com.example.thibault.project_mobile E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:451)

Comment: Are you getting some exception if yes please post your logcat.

Comment: TextView with `textView1 ` id is inside `listanswer_home ` layout or in `test_edit_text ` ?

Comment: I add xml file, two seconds

Comment: it's done, if you have any idea ^^'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The error is in the adapter : text.setText(answer.getAnswer());

Because `TextView` with `textView1` id is only available in `listanswer_home.xml` layout not in `test_edit_text.xml` and if `if (childPosition < getChildrenCount(groupPosition) - 1)` condition is `false` retuning `test_edit_text.xml` layout from `getChildView` and `convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);` return `null`.

Either add `null` check before calling `setText` method of `TextView` as:

```
 if(text !=null){
    text.setText(answer.getAnswer());
  }
```

or add `TextView` with `textView1` in `listanswer_home.xml`.

Comment: Oh perfect it's working :D. I will try to understand it now.
Thank you !

Comment: But I don't really understand why if the condition is false then we go after to the line convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1).

Because if it's the footer we go in the else and we never see this line ?